# three js getting coordinates of mesh.lookAt(object);

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have `scene`,`meshes` and target `object`.

When i set up

> mesh.lookAt(object)

**mesh** correctly facing of **object**.

How can i repeat this rotation of **mesh** on another mesh, to force another mesh facing the same direction (not the same object, but the same orientation as a first mesh have)?

How can i get rotation coordinates of first **mesh**?

How can i get this coordinates without need of creating mesh and order `mesh.lookAt(object)`. That mean only to calculate this coordinates without need to use it on some object?

**UPDATE:**
Only possible solution is to create new `THREE.Object3D()` and use `object.lookAt(target)`. Then repeat rotation for all later loaded object like: `new_object.rotation.set(object.rotation.x,object.rotation.y,object.rotation.z)`
You will create only one Object, not a lot of unuseful Vector3-s.

Do not use  `new_object.rotation = object.rotation` it is functional solution, but a variables stay connected. Change of `object` rotation, will update `new_object.rotation` too (renderer is updating all values each frame).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the local rotation of the other meshes to the local rotation of the mech facing in the correct direction.

```
anyOtherMesh.rotation = mesh.rotation;
```

Comment: Hi, thx, but how can i access that values if i don't have that object rotated. I thing, I want to know and get values of rotation and apply to second mesh, but i dont want to rotate first mesh.

Comment: Real situation: I have s ship, before start flying i need to rotate ship to the target. I'm using (object.lookAt(myWayTarget) but that will jump in travel position, this looks ugly) I need to animate that rotation. That is the reason, why i need a coordinates before is the ship rotated exactly, to animate smooth move to this rotation.
It wont be smart to make another object, rotate it and use AnotherObject.rotation as s finishing coordinates for animation, but i cant find another way.

Answer (score 0):

what about a 
lookAt( new THREE.Vector3( target.position.x, target.position.y, target.position.z ) 
?

Comment: Which one of the three questions does this address?

Comment: Updated question with best known solution.

Comment: @paul it means new vector3 each frame on each rotated object. I think it is a trivial action,  should be more cost saving. In this case you need always create new Vector and recalculate Matrix rotation with lookAt function, when you have results finished and ready from first object...